# Soring data ascending in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort data from 3 tables, but based on the total value that has been calculated automatically.

This is my code:

```php
$query = mysqli_query($konek,"select * from klasifikasi join siswa on siswa.id_siswa=klasifikasi.id_siswa join prodi on prodi.id_prodi=siswa.id_prodi where klasifikasi.id_klasifikasi ORDER BY klasifikasi.raport_mtk DESC, klasifikasi.raport_bindo DESC");
    while ($dataku = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $total = ((($dataku['raport_mtk'])/7) +
    (($dataku['raport_bindo'])/7)+
    (($dataku['raport_bing'])/7)+
    (($dataku['raport_ipa'])/7)+
    (($dataku['un_mtk'])/7)+
    (($dataku['un_ipa'])/7)+
    (($dataku['psikotest'])/7)*0.75)-
    ((($dataku['raport_ips'])/4)+
    (($dataku['un_bindo'])/4)+
    (($dataku['un_bing'])/4)+
    (($dataku['npa'])/4)*0.25);
```

Later I want to sort the value from the largest based on the `$total`. I've tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do the calculation and the sorting in the query. Simpler and clearer.

```sql
SELECT *,
    (raport_mtk+raport_bindo+raport_bing+raport_ipa+un_mtk+un_ipa+psikotest)/7*0.75-
    (raport_ips+un_bindo+un_bing+npa)/4*0.25 AS total 
FROM klasifikasi 
    JOIN siswa ON siswa.id_siswa=klasifikasi.id_siswa 
    JOIN prodi ON prodi.id_prodi=siswa.id_prodi 
WHERE klasifikasi.id_klasifikasi 
ORDER BY total
```

Comment: Thank You. already bro. now I want to print all the names of students by major. but when I click print, only 1 student's name from that department is printed. please give a solution bro. this my coding : $query = mysqli_query($konek,"SELECT *,
    (raport_mtk+raport_bindo+raport_bing+raport_ipa+un_mtk+un_ipa+psikotest)/7*0.75-
    (raport_ips+un_bindo+un_bing+npa)/4*0.25 AS total 
FROM klasifikasi 
    JOIN siswa ON siswa.id_siswa=klasifikasi.id_siswa 
    JOIN prodi ON prodi.id_prodi=siswa.id_prodi 
WHERE siswa.id_prodi='$id_prodi' 
ORDER BY total DESC");

Comment: Bro, you are giving no information at all, if we don;t know what you are talking about, nobody can help you.

Be clear, Precise. Give all the relevant information, like the data, the table, the wanted results, the attained results. Any used platforms or software. What do you mean by "print"? Are you in MS Word  or something? We cannot just guess what you have there.

Comment: Also be VERY careful with using PHP variables in your queries like `WHERE siswa.id_prodi='$id_prodi' ORDER BY total DESC`. You may end up being hacked within 5 seconds, and all your data may be gone. Google "SQL injection". Seriously, before you program anything else, do that.